# extracting letters and numbers from a string

Tags: c

I have some difficulties with an assigned homework and wondered if I could get some help..
Anyway the task is: "You have to enter random letters and numbers from the keyboard. The string should be analised from the program, after that all numbers must be extracted and it also has to sum them up.
e.g. Input: asd-12sdf45-56asdf100  Output:77

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<ctype.h> 
#include<string.h> 

int main() { 
    char stringText[50]; 
    char arraySaver[50]; 

    int i=0, j=0, k=0; 

    printf("Enter String: "); 
    scanf("%s", &stringText); 

    for(i=0; i<strlen(stringText); i++) { 
        if(isdigit(stringText[i])) { 
            arraySaver[j]=stringText[i]; 
            j++; 
        } 
    } 

    system("pause"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Have you put any effort into solving the problem yourself? Can you show us your code?

Comment: Start by looking up the available [string and character functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) and [input/output functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io), I'm sure you'll find something usable there.

Comment: @VivinPaliath Welcome. (Which one was that? I don't even remember.)

Comment: "I have some difficulties" - It's hard to help you with them if you don't tell us what they are.

Comment: [20:18:56] WildTurtle...: #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
  char stringText[50];
  char arraySaver[50];
  int i=0, j=0, k=0;
  printf("Enter String: ");
  scanf("%s", &stringText);
  for(i=0; i<strlen(stringText); i++)
  {
    if(isdigit(stringText[i])) 
    {
      arraySaver[j]=stringText[i];
      j++;
    }
  }
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}

Comment: @IliyanNinov, please add it to your question, not a comment. Also, please mention exactly where your problem is.

Comment: @IliyanNinov: When asking a question, please remember to include something like: "When I run this code, I expect to see <X>, but instead I see <Y>."

Comment: static const char input[] = "asd-12sdf45-56asdf100";

int sum(void) 
{
    int i;
    int currentNumber = 0;
    int finalSum = 0;
    int sign = 1;

    for(i=0; input[i]; i++)
    {
        if(isdigit(input[i]))
        {
            currentNumber = (currentNumber * 10) + (input[i] - '0');
        }
        else         
        {
            finalSum += currentNumber * sign;
            currentNumber = 0;
            sign = 1;
            if(input[i] == '-')
            {
                sign = -1;
            }
        }
    }

    finalSum += currentNumber;
}

Answer (score 3):

Since this is homework, I'm not going to write out the code for the solution. However, you *are* pretty close. You have your array of digits. All you need to do now is:

1. Iterate over `arraySaver`.
2. Print out each element.
3. Maintain a running total in an external variable, say `sum`.
4. Outside the loop, print `sum`.

**UPDATE**

I am not sure what the requirements of the homework are, but if you need to look at individual digits then you are ok. But if you need to look at negative numbers, or if you need to consider runs of a digits as a single number, then you will need to do more work:

1. If the character is negative, then you assume that it could be a negative number; set a flag marking it as such.
2. If the character is a number, then assume that it is the start of a number. Continue reading until you encounter a non-numeric character, while keeping track of each digit.
3. Save the number you have read so far while taking into account the sign (i.e., your flag that says whether it is negative or not).

The rest of the code should be similar.

Comment: He also needs some way of keeping his digits separate and to find negative signs.  Right now, his array saver will look like 124556100 when it needs to be -12 45 -56 100. Either as a 2dim array or with a separator of some sort.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan The requirements aren't clear; I can see splitting out negative numbers, but how would you separate multidigit numbers from a random string? How can you tell if 1231 is 1, 2, 3, 1 or 1, 23, 1, or some other combination?

Comment: From the sample input, I think you would look for a "garbage" character in between the numbers as that is the only way I get his answer of 77.  BTW, I agree that the requirements are far too vague and open to interpretation.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan I see what you are saying. You could interpret it as a run of numbers between non-numeric characters.

Answer (score 2):

You're close, but you should use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`, then parse the string via other means (ie: `sscanf`, to avoid various issues with capturing newline characters, etc). If all you have to do is sum single digits, this will work. For something more complicated (ie: abc12abc in the case of this code is summed as "one plus two" rather than evaluated as "twelve"), you would need more complicated logic.

Here's a hint: you'll need another loop within the existing loop that looks like `while(isdigit[k++])`. Good luck!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX_BUF_LENGTH  (50)

int main(void) {
   char buf[MAX_BUF_LENGTH]     = { 0 };
   char digits[MAX_BUF_LENGTH]  = { 0 };
   char temp[MAX_BUF_LENGTH]    = { 0 };
   int i, j;
   int sum = 0;

   printf("Enter String: ");
   fgets (buf,MAX_BUF_LENGTH,stdin);

   /* Analyze the input string, and backup each digit while maintaining
    * a running sum.
    */
   for(i=0,j=0; i<strlen(buf); i++) {
      if(isdigit(buf[i])) {
         digits[j] = buf[i];
         j++;
         snprintf(temp, MAX_BUF_LENGTH, "%c", buf[i]);
         sum += atoi(temp);
      }
   }
   printf("Original String:%s\n", buf);
   printf("Digit String:   %s\n", digits);
   printf("Sum of Digits:  %d\n", sum);

   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: From the output section of his answer, he needs the more "complex" logic of tracking multi-digit numbers and negative signs.  Don't give it to him directly though.  This is supposed to be for learning.

Comment: Taking Dogbert's Solution as reference I got something of my own. 
This should help. :)

http://paste.ubuntu.com/5592886/

Comment: @nimish Well done. Could you post your code as an answer so it's stored in its entirety on SO?

Comment: @Dogbert No I am afraid I wont be able to do so as the question is closed. My code still needs fine tuning. Eg:- I have not use fgets. :P Left deliberate;y loop holes so that he actually reads both our solution implements understanding what is done and why :)